# Different state storage behavior for "Back" vs "Home"

Tags: android, android-activity, state

I am still learning the ins and outs of Android development.  I am playing around with the Notepad tutorial application to try and get different behavior.

Right now, I want to have the application do the following in the NoteEdit activity:

1) If the Back button is pressed, current state is ignored; basically, it's like an implicit cancel, and you are taken back to the list.

2) If the Home button is pressed, it takes you to the home page as normal.  However, if you open the application again, it should go back into the NoteEdit activity in the same state as when you left (IE, if you were partway through an edit, for example).

I removed the "saveState" stuff from onPause, because I don't want to store to the DB unless "Confirm" is pressed (instead, I moved the call to saveState to the confirm button).  By doing this, hitting "Back" basically throws out your changes, which is what I want.  However, going Home and coming back also throws out your changes, though it does remain in the NoteEdit activity.  Both "Back" and "Home" cause the onPause message to trigger, and both cause onResume to trigger (either from clicking on the item in the "Back" case, or by going back into the app in the "Home" case).

Is there a way to have these two events handle saving the state differently?  Is it possible to have the Home button store the state (temporarily), while not having the Back button do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an onSaveInstanceState method, but instead of saving to the DB (as in the Notepad sample), save your Activity's state to the Bundle. You then need to recover from the saved state in your onCreate when the passed in Bundle is non-null.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually did have code in the onSaveInstanceState method, though after using the debugger, onCreate never got called when I went to the Application list and restarted it.

Comment: Pushed enter too soon, sorry.  I noticed that the "onResume" had the populateFields() method, which was resetting it.  When I removed it, the behavior is as I expected now:  I even tested it by manually killing the process and restarting, and it still works.  Thus, I think the onCreate is still needed for that case.